# Jquery addClass on a name scroll position

Tags: jquery, css, scrolltop

I have this code in place to scroll to a `<a name tag>`. This is all fine, but my question is: If I were to scroll to New Message, instead of using the link, can I get jQuery to add an `active` class to the Go To link?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#about">Go To</a><li>
<a name="about">New Message</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href^=#]').click(function(e) {
        var name = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        var pos = $('a[name=' + name + ']').offset();
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: pos.top
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tell me if this is what you are asking: Once you scroll down to "New Message" on the screen, the fact that it scrolled down there activates the the code that will add a class to "Go To"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this simple Jquery plug-in http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

then you could write

```
$('[name = 'about']').waypoint(function(){
$('[href = '#about']').addClass('active');
});
```

I haven't tested that but its the basic idea.

Comment: I can also attest to the usefulness of this plugin!

Comment: yeah i actually had to do this in plain JavaScript the other day and now i appreciate the plug-in even more haha

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(e){
    jQuery("a[name]").removeClass("visible");
    jQuery("a[name]").each(function(index, item){
      var pos = jQuery(this).offset();
      if(pos.top > jQuery(window).scrollTop()
         && pos.top < jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height()){
        // My anchor is in the viewport, let's add it a class.
        jQuery(this).addClass("visible");
      }
    });
});
```

EDIT: My answer was incorrect. I edited it and made a pen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/twDek